# SQLAlchemy filter for many-to-many relationship with multiple requirements

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables, Recipe and Ingredient, and they have a many-to-many relationship between them (Recipe.ingredients and Ingredient.recipes).

I can get a list of recipes which contain a certain ingredient by using one of these queries:

```
Recipe.query.filter(Recipe.ingredients.any(Ingredient.name == 'LEMON JUICE'))
Recipe.query.join(Recipe.ingredients).filter(Ingredient.name == 'KOSHER SALT')
```

And I can get a list of recipes which contain either ingredient by using in_():

```
Recipe.query.filter(Recipe.ingredients.any(Ingredient.name.in_(['LEMON JUICE','KOSHER SALT'])))
Recipe.query.join(Recipe.ingredients).filter(Ingredient.name.in_(['LEMON JUICE','KOSHER SALT']))
```

But I just can't figure out how to get a short list of recipes which have both ingredients.

It doesn't seem like you can simply filter the results with another filter, when filtering on that related table column.  None of the examples I found online were for combining filters on related table columns, only for the current table.

I can probably just query for one ingredient then filter it out using Python, but I know I'm just missing something to make this work at the query level.

I've tried to figure this out by reading the SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLAlchemy docs, and using inline help, but I'm pretty stuck so I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: What happens if you chain the filters? e.g. `Recipe.query.join(Recipe.ingredients).filter(Ingredient.name=='KOSHER SALT').filter(Ingredient.name=='LEMON JUICE')` Do you get zero results?

Comment: Yes, I get zero results.  I have been using Python sets to combine/filter different queries, but I would rather understand how to create one giant query to return only the matches I'm looking for.